# How to change (automatically) order status Pending to Processing when payment (credit card) is accepted?

Tags: order-status, status

I use `Cybersource simple redirect extension` and i would like to `change order status to processing when payment is accepted`.
Current status for all orders (cancelled, refused, accepted, ...) is pending... I simply would like to get a different status for paid order.
Can someone help ?

Comment: which extension ,you have use?i have work  on it few day earlier.

Comment: I use : CyberSource Simple Redirect Payment Method [link](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/cybersource-simple-redirect-payment-method-1.html)

Comment: give me the link of extension. i have use extesion http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/cybersource-secure-acceptance-web-mobile.html

Comment: The link is : [http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/cybersource-simple-redirect-payment-method-1.html](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/cybersource-simple-redirect-payment-method-1.html)

Comment: I've tried Cactimedia extension also but it didn't work properly...

Comment: it may  work. you need get proper support from  cybersource...

Comment: I'm in touch with cybersource Singapour... they don't provide strong technical support.

Comment: have you set return url of your site at cybersource system?

Comment: Yes, I have. There is a redirect link to my website once translation is completed

Comment: please tell me url?

Comment: www.delishop.co.th/home (test version).

Comment: no no... i want the return url which has been set at cybersource account

Comment: I don't understand you mean cybersource back office adress ?

Comment: there should  setting at cybersource payment account panel,where you can set return url....... after payment done at cybersource page

Comment: Having same issue with Cybersource payment(used simple redirect extension), after successful payment I have redirected to my custom response page after click on 'Return to website' botton. but still order status is not getting updated(from pending to processing)..Please help me